# Custom load balancing algorithm with mod_cluster

Tags: algorithm, jboss, wildfly, mod-cluster

I have recently found out that mod_cluster offers more capabilities than mod_proxy or similiar modules. Hence there are dynamic deployment and new metrics available for the load balancing I have a question if there is a possibility to write own load balancing algorithm instead of using predefined ones. If so where to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible. You need following steps:

1. Create custom load metric by extending `AbstractLoadMetric`
2. Package the custom load metric as a JAR
3. Copy JAR to modcluster module
4. Update `module.xml` to include the custom load metric JAR
5. Update standalone/domain config XML to use custom load metric

See sample example here: https://github.com/Karm/mod_cluster-custom-load-metric

**NOTE:** WildFly 9 will bring improvement in this mechanism to avoid editing of `module.xml`. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-372

Comment: Thank you for your answear, it's very helpful. As I understand I should repeat this steps on each node of the cluster setting its capacity, history and weight properties to customize load distribution?

Comment: Yes, if you are using standalone mode. If you are using domain mode, then  step 5 is only required to be done once to update domain.xml for the relevant profile(s).